# V-C++ on Windows 7 Program connected to comm port locks up after sitting idle.

Tags: c++, visual-c++, windows-7, serial-port

I have a program compiled with Visual C++ that is locking up when re-activated (by mouse click or key press) after sitting idle for ~ 15 minutes.  The program is connected to a comm port and actively reads data and updates screen with a value every second or two while sitting idle.  But if there has been no mouse or key activity for awhile (15 minutes or more), when operator then clicks a button or hot key, the program OCCASIONALLY locks up. Have also observed that if you wait for awhile when it is locked up, it will eventually free itself.
Any ideas on what's causing it and how to fix it?

Comment: Deadlocks are easy to debug, you've got lots of time to use Debug + Break All.  If you need help then at least a stack trace is required.  See if WinKey+L (lock workstation) helps to trigger the deadlock, that's a pretty common threading bug inducer.

Comment: I think you are correct about it being a deadlock issue. I'm still looking into the problem. Thanks for the hints.  I'll post updates.